# Does Nash Theorem imply Zermelo's Theorem?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

In 2-Player zero-sum game with every information open and no probabilistic strategy required, Nash Theorem states that one of the players has a strategy, in which the player can maintain a situation where he/she can only become worse off. Does this mean that one of the players has a winning(or drawing) strategy? That is, does Nash Theorem imply Zermelo's Theorem?

Comment: Just skimming the wikipedia page for Nash equilibrium (I don't know any game theory), it seems like the Nash theorem allows for "mixed strategies," which results in probabilities of victory, rather than "forced victory".

Comment: @CharlesMcCharles Oh, your point is right, but I meant to say games where no probabilistic strategies are required. I edited the question. Thank you for your comment